# VSCode hangs when attempting to build dotnet project

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code

I had been using Visual Studio Code with a netcore 3.1 project without any issues.

After being away for about a week, I tried to continue development. However, when I run the build task from VSCode, the terminal shows

```
> Executing task: dotnet build /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary <
```

and hangs indefinitely. Running `dotnet build` from the console works fine.

How can I use VSCode for debugging again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a general issue with the terminal, and not specific to `dotnet`.

A temporary fix was to run `vscode` from the terminal (instead of clicking the desktop icon).

After system upgrades and restarting this problem disappeared.